# Defensive copying in terms of a reference parameter to a constructor

Tags: java, defensive-copy

Can anyone please tell me what is defensive copying in terms of a reference parameter to a constructor of a class in JAVA

Thanks sooooo much

Comment: Did you try Google or the search facility here first?

Comment: I guess you will have to tell us what "*a reference parameter to a constructor*" is first.

Comment: I did search on the google but no answers and thats the place i was wondering what is "a reference parameter to a constructor"

Comment: do you know what "defencive copy" is?

Comment: yes, i know what is defensive copying. it's just i don't know how to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what I can extract from the question, I guess the problem can be summarized as follows...

Let us start with this:

```
class NotSafeAtAll
{
    private final List<X> list;

    public NotSafeAtAll(final List<X> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

This class has a huge problem: it copies the list *reference* as its member field. This means that if the caller of the constructor modifies this list, changes will be reflected in the `NotSafeAtAll` instance as well.

And this is where "defensive copying" comes into play. Consider:

```
class ALittleMoreSafe
{
    private final List<X> list;

    public ALittleMoreSafe(final List<X> list)
    {
        this.list = new ArrayList<X>(list);
    }
}
```

Now, the class has its own copy of the list; if the caller modifies the list it has passed as an argument to the constructor, the `ALittleMoreSafe` instance will not be affected.

But the story does not end here, of course. Now consider that there is a method in the latter class to *return* the list it has received as a parameter:

```
class ALittleMoreSafe
{
    private final List<X> list;

    public ALittleMoreSafe(final List<X> list)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<X>(list);
    }

    public List<X> unsafeGetList()
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

You lose! Even if your constructor is safe, the fact is that you return the reference to your internal list; and the caller can modify the list via this reference.

Here again, defensive copy can save you, but there is a better solution: ensure that the list you return is immutable:

```
public List<X> safeGetList()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Any attempt of the caller to modify the returned list will fail.

So, is the story over?

NO.

It can only be over if all `X` instances are immutable. Unfortunately, the very classical, and overused, bean pattern anything but guarantees that. But this is another story.